# How to write/read a message from Google Drive text file with Email Id and Password from ASP.Net Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I want to read/write some content to Google Drive Programmatically from a ASP.NET MVC Application. Here i want to use Email ID and Password as hot coded instead of navigating user to authentication page.

I looked at some examples, all are redirecting user to Google authentication page. But My requirement is to use a fixed Google user account.

Answer (score 0):

You can no longer use username/password for authentication. Just let go of it.

You can use the steps in the answer here [How do I authorise an app (web or installed) without user intervention? (canonical ?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-a-background-web-app-without-user-intervention-canonical) to achieve what you are looking for